# What types are these two sentences with imperative clauses

Tags: complex-sentences, compound-sentences

Quotes are from The Old Man and the Sea by Ernest Hemingway

> ```
> Remember, no matter how little you want to, that you must eat him in the morning.
>
> Remember, he said to himself.
> ```

I thought the second one would be a complex sentence as it is a similar pattern to direct speech ("Remember," he said. - that would be complex, right?) but I'm not sure anymore, as it feels like imperative clause "Remember" can stand on its own.

Similarly, at first, I thought that the first sentence is complex-compound but if the "Remember" is an independent clause it can't be. How is it, then?

Thank you

Comment: I would say that "remember" is an interjection in the second case.

Comment: Remember works like an imperative sentence/ clause here. That way, the first sentence has one independent clause and two dependent ones.  Second example has one independent clause 'remember (=You remember...) and one dependent clause. That way both are complex sentences.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remember, *no matter how little you want to*, that you must eat him in the morning.

For clarity we can move the fronting adverbial:

Remember {that you must eat him in the morning *no matter how little you want to.*}

Verb +S  …{……………..content or noun clause as object………………………….}

In essence, this is no different from

Remember it

2. Likewise:

He said to himself “Remember” - is basically, “He said it to himself”

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it isn't completely clear to me, yet. Are you saying that both of the sentences are simple sentences? With "that you must eat him in the morning" clause being the object of the first sentence and "Remember" being of the second one?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would see it. The reported or direct speech that creates the object should be seen as one indivisible unit. Of course, it might be a complex sentence itself, but it is not within the analysis of the whole.